# How to define a function in arduino code to connect wifi module with arduino uno

Tags: function, arduino

This is my first arduino project. I have this error when uploading my arduino code. I want to send serial key data from wifi module through arduino to a web page..how do I correct the error?

It says `findok was not declared in this scope` Below is the code...

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
SoftwareSerial espSerial(1,0)
String USSD ="";
Sting PASSWD ="" ;
// connect to wifi 
void connectWifi() {
    Serial.println(">> Connecting to wifi network..");
    espSerial.print("AT+CWJAP_\"" + USSD + "\",\"" + PASSWD + "\"\r\n";
    //serialPipe();
    //delay(4000)
    if (findOk) {
        Serial.Println("[OK] connected Successfully to Access point");
    } 
    else {
        Serial.Println("An error has occured. Failed to connect!
        Please check network configurations settings. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using software serial on hardware serial pins? Just use hardware serial.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self explaining. You're using the variable `findOk` where it has not been declared. How to avoid that error? Declare the variable or don't use it.

Your compiler does not know `findOk`, hence it cannot make sense of your code.
You have to tell the compiler what findOk is.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations

This is very very basic C++ knowledge. Consider reading a book or at least doing a beginners tutorial for C++ and Arduino.

You should start with something simpler. There is so much wrong with your code that I do not know where to begin. Get the basics done or you won't enjoy programming for long.

Comment: this answer was posted befor somone edited out most of the syntax errors in the question...

Comment: Seems like someone edited out most of the code as well.  Including the original error in question.